# When using Composer to Install Magento, "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, composer-php, magento2

I'm now using Composer to Install Magento, when inputting

```
composer create-project \
  --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/magento/project-community-edition=2.4.6-p1 \
  Magento 2
```

it soon returned me with the following error:

---

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

1. Problem 1

   - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.6-p1].
   - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.6-p1 requires ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
2. Problem 2

   - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[4.2.1, ..., 4.3.2] require ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
   - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^4.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[4.2.1, 4.3.0, 4.3.1, 4.3.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

- C:\php-8.2.7\php.ini

You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd --ignore-platform-req=ext-intl` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

---

I suppose the solution is to verify extensions are enabled in my phi.ini file.

However, I really don't know how to verify and enable them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ2Ms.png)

Comment: How did you install php on that system or who did install it? PHP normally ships with documentation (at least within the comments _in_ the .ini file), so you could locate it (Composer wrote where it is), then open it with a text-editor and read it from top to bottom. Additionally the PHP manual is available on the https://php.net/ website. -- And have you tried what the error message suggests at the end? (slightly edited for markdown, please check everything is in order)

Comment: Thanks, my php was download from php.net, it asks me to verify gd etension and intl extension. I don't know how to enable them.

Comment: Go to the website where you got PHP from and read the manual. It has one general section about how to enable extensions, and each extension has a section which documents installation requirements as well as the configuration of that extension. That is an alternative approach to reading the ini file.